# Reading a Complex CSV format Into Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, matrix

```
4,7,33  308:0.364759856031284 1156:0.273818346738286 1523:0.17279792082766 9306:0.243665855423149 
7,4,33  1156:0.185729429759684 1681:0.104443202690279 5351:0.365670526234034 6212:0.0964006003127458
```

I have a textfile in the above format. The first 3 columns are labels and need to be extracted into another file keeping the order intact.

As one proceeds through the file, each row has varying number of labels. I have been reading the csvread function in Matlab but that is generic and would not work in the above case.

Next, I need to extract

```
308:0.364759856031284 1156:0.273818346738286 1523:0.17279792082766 9306:0.243665855423149
```

such that at column **308** in the Matrix for Row **1**, I put in the value **0.364759856031284**.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've taken the liberty of formatting your question a bit better. You will find that paying attention to little things like grammar and formatting will help you get better quality answers!

Comment: Thanks for this Shepmaster. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your row format changes you need to read the file line by line

> ```
> fid = fopen(filename, 'rt'); % open file for text reading
> resultMatrix = []; % start with empty matrix 
> while 1   
>   line = fgetl(fid);  
>   if ~ischar(line), break, end
>   % get the value separators, :
>   seps = strfind(line, ':');
>   % get labels
>   whitespace = iswhite(line(1:seps(1)-1)); % get white space
>   lastWhite = find(whitespace, 'last'); % get last white space pos
>   labelString = deblank(line(1:lastWhite)); % string with all labels separated by ,
>   labelString(end+1) = ','; % add final , to match way of extraction
>   ix = strfind(labelString, ','); % get pos of ,
>   labels = zeros(numel(ix),1); % create the labels array
>   start = 1;
>   for n1 = 1:numel(labels)
>     labels(n1,1) = str2num(labelString(start:ix(n1)-1));
>   end
>   % continue and do a similar construction for the COL:VALUE pairs
>   % If you do not know how many rows and columns your final matrix will have
>   % you need to continuously update the size 1 row for each loop and
>   % then add new columns if any of the current rows COLs are outside current matrix
>   cols = zeros(numel(seps,1);
>   values = cols;
>   for n1 = 1:numel(seps)
>     % find out current columns start pos and value end pos using knowledge of
>     % the separator, :, position and that whitespace separates COL:VALUE pairs
>     cols(n1,1) = str2num(line(colStart:seps(n1)-1));
>     values(n1,1) = str2num(line(seps(n1)+1:valueEnd));
>   end
>   if isempty(resultMatrix)
>     resultMatrix = zeros(1,max(cols)); % make the matrix large enough to hold the last col
>   else
>     [nR,nC] = size(resultMatrix); % get current size
>     if max(cols) > nC
>       % add columns to resultMatrix so we still can fit column data
>       resultMatrix = [resultMatrix, zeros(nR, max(cols)-nC)];
>     end
>     % add row
>     resultMatrix = [resultMatrix;zeros(1,max(nC,max(cols)))];
>   end
>   % loop through cols and values and populate the resultMatrix with wanted data
> end
> fclose(fid);
> ```

Note, the above code is untested so it will contain errors but it should be easy to fix.
I purposely left out minor parts and it should not be too difficult filling that out.

Comment: Thank you for this. I decided to write a C++ script that reads each line and then splits the text based on the delimiters. I will try you code now and thank you so much for this.